# CSS issue, dropdown menu showing white space

Tags: html, css

So I have been practincing CSS and html, and so far I haven't been able to fix this. Basically the button shows some white space below the image in the dropdown menu. I have the code here

http://jsfiddle.net/BVN9G/

HTML

```
<ul id="nav" class="drop">
        <! Boton de Inicio>
        <li id="main">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/6PmX8Bw.png" border="0" height="50px" width="66px" style="top:3px; z-index:1;"  />
            <ul>
                <li><a id="drop1" href="mensaje_content.html" target="_self">Mensaje del presidente</a></li>
                <li><a id="drop1" href="pasos_en_verde.html" target="_self">Lo m&aacute;s destacado</a></li>
                <li><a id="drop1" href="perfil_Org.html" target="_self">Perfil de la Organizaci&oacute;n</a></li>
                <li id="seleccionada"><font color="#5AAF92">Gobierno corporativo</font></li>
                <li><a id="drop1" href="BaBF.html" target="_self">Brindando un mejor futuro</a></li>
                <li><a id="drop1">An&aacute;lisis stakeholders</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
```

CSS

```
ul#nav {margin: -2px;}
        ul.drop a { display:block; color: #058052; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 14px; text-decoration: none;}
        ul.drop, ul.drop li, ul.drop ul { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 1px solid #058052; background: #fff; color: #058052;}
        ul.drop { position: relative; z-index: 597; float: left; }
        ul.drop li { float: left; line-height: 1.3em; vertical-align: middle; zoom: 1; padding: 5px 10px; }
        ul.drop li.hover, ul.drop li:hover { position: relative; z-index: 599; cursor: default; background: #058052; color: #fff; }
        ul.drop ul { visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; z-index: 598; width: 195px; background: #058052; }
        ul.drop ul li { float: none; }
        ul.drop ul ul { top: -2px; left: 100%; }
        ul.drop li:hover > ul { visibility: visible }
        ul.drop li a:hover{background: #058052; color: #fff;}
        ul.drop li:hover>a {background: #058052; color: #fff;}
        li#main {padding:0px; border: 0px; display: block; background:transparent; border-color:transparent; color:transparent; }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the vertical-align property of the image to top:

```
img {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/BVN9G/1/)**

Or set the image to display:block.

```
img {
    display:block;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2qHqz/)**

Note that in both examples the CSS will target all your images, so make the selector more specific to suit your needs.

Answer (score 3):

```
li#main {
padding: 0px;
border: 0px;
display: block;
background: transparent;
border-color: transparent;
color: transparent;
height: 50px;
}
```

adding the height will fix

Answer (score 1):

Try This(modified line 5    ul.drop.li)

```
line-height:0.3em
```

Replace Your code Put this one:

```
ul#nav {margin: -2px;}
    ul.drop a { display:block; color: #058052; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 14px; text-decoration: none;}
    ul.drop, ul.drop li, ul.drop ul { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 1px solid #058052; background: #fff; color: #058052;}
    ul.drop { position: relative; z-index: 597; float: left; }
    ul.drop li { float: left; line-height: 0.3em; vertical-align: middle; zoom: 1; padding: 5px 10px; }
    ul.drop li.hover, ul.drop li:hover { position: relative; z-index: 599; cursor: default; background: #058052; color: #fff; }
    ul.drop ul { visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; z-index: 598; width: 195px; background: #058052; }
    ul.drop ul li { float: none; }
    ul.drop ul ul { top: -2px; left: 100%; }
    ul.drop li:hover > ul { visibility: visible }
    ul.drop li a:hover{background: #058052; color: #fff;}
    ul.drop li:hover>a {background: #058052; color: #fff;}
    li#main {padding:0px; border: 0px; display: block; background:transparent; border-color:transparent; color:transparent; }
```

Comment: Since the OP took the time to provide a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem, it might be an idea to do the same with your solution. It will also make it more likely you'll get upvotes as "casual" readers (like myself) will be able to see it works instantly.